# get current thread id in gmail using google app script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am building a Gmail Add-On. I want to get the **thread Id** of current open email thread using Google Apps Script. I tried to figure out in Google Developers documentation for **GmailApp**. But nothing found relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve `messageId` of the current message from `e.messageMetadata.messageId` of `buildAddOn(e)`. Using this, you can retrieve `threadId` as follows.

```
var threadId = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId).getThread().getId();
```

#### References :

- [getMessageById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getMessageById(String))
- [getThread()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getthread)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: It's working. But **threadId and messageId are same for the first message in the thread**. If there is only one message in the thread then messageId and threadId will be same.

Comment: @Jai Prak Yes. You are correct. If there are some messages in a thread, other message IDs are difference from the thread ID.