# Google Scripts extracting a specific ID

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to figure out how to pull a unique identifier from a Gmail message. I've got the body pulled with:

```
function myFunction() {  
  var emails = GmailApp.search('label:company-email subject:"Specific Criteria" ',1,10);  
  for (x=0;x<emails.length;x++){  
  var thread = emails[x].getMessages()[0].getPlainBody();  
  var UID; //  need this varible to be set as the extracted UID formatted UID### with 3 possibly 4 numbers. It will always have the same starting "UID"  
  } 
}
```

> UID: need this varible to be set as the extracted UID formatted UID### with 3 possibly 4 numbers. It will always have the same starting "UID"

Edit:
I have researched regex to see if I could get the data with a regular experession, however i'm in over my head there and I'm not understanding it.

I also tried `indexOf()`, but when I search the thread it gives me a -1. I tested to make sure I had `indexOf()` correct by testing it with a phrase and the UID, and it pulls when I have a regular string, just not from the body of the email. Maybe I'm missing a conversion somewhere?

Edit #2:

Here is a sample of the email being received:

```
 Good afternoon user,
 
 Please contact *Company Name* (UID123) (*City,State*) (*additional info*) at your earliest convenience. 
 
 Thank you,
```

I deleted the regex and am gonna be honest I don't remember exactly what I tested. was doing that late last night.

Edit 3:
turned out I was doing something wrong with regex. got an answer and I needed the following:
`var UID = thread.match("UID[0-9]+");` worked like a charm.
Thank you guys for helping.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: You need to provide a sample email text with id and body with new lines and other control characters. Add a regex you attempted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get current thread id in gmail using google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267172/get-current-thread-id-in-gmail-using-google-app-script)

Comment: @imvain2 Don't think it's the same id. OP is probably looking for some custom id in the body of the email and not the id of the email itself.

Comment: yeah looking for a custom ID. Thanks though. since it's a company account, i'm recreating it on my personal email to avoid issues. will post comment with requested info shortly.

Comment: Your regex is invalid

Comment: I'll make the appropriate changes. thx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [string#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- `\d+` - one or more digits

  ```js
  const msg = `Good afternoon user,
   
   Please contact *Company Name* (UID123) (*City,State*) (*additional info*) at your earliest convenience. 
   
   Thank you,`;
  console.log(msg.match(/UID(\d+)/)[1])
  ```